# Chemical sentences! Decrypting

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

## Background

You are sitting in chemistry class and your friend keep sending you these strange letters. It is your job to decrypt the messages into words.

*This is the inverse of [this challenge.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64858/8478)*

[image]

## The Challenge

**Input**: A list or a string of integers from 1 to 118.

**Output**: The words for each chemical element if possible. Otherwise return False, throw an error, or blank. Note in your program 0 must return a whitespace or newline. Ignore all integers not in range.

**Test cases**
Input 1:

```
9 53 75
```

Output 1:

```
fire
```

Input 2:

```
91 120 91
```

Output 2:

```
papa
```

Input 3:

```
9 53 75 0 53 16 0 9 92 7
```

Output 3:

```
fire is fun
```

**Note**: Again no built in functions for generating the periodic system or external libaries. Standard loopholes are not allowed.

## Scoring

Submissions will be scored in **bytes**. I recommend [this website](http://bytesizematters.com) to keep track of your byte count, though you can use any counter you like.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the lowest score wins!

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61969/8478)

Comment: [Borderline dupe](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11816/194)

Comment: Does the output have to be in lowecase or can it be mixed case (for example `FIRe IS FUN` or `PaPa`)?

Comment: Mixed cases are fine =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 264 bytes

```
s@L+" "-R0+c"h0helibeb0c0n0o0f0nenamgalsip0s0clark0casctiv0crmnfeconicuzngageassebrkrrbsry0zrnbmotcrurhpdagcdinsnsbtei0xecsbalaceprndpmsmeugdtbdyhoertmybluhftaw0reosirptauhgtlpbbipoatrnfrraacthpau0nppuamcmbkcfesfmmdnolrrfdbsgbhhsmtdsrgcn"2c"uutfl0uuplv0uusuuo"3rz7
```

Comment: Use packed str?

Comment: @isaacg Last time I tried to use it it was all buggy :(

Comment: TIL that the periodic table contains "clark".

Comment: But no "kent" :-(

Answer (score 2):

## [Par](http://ypnypn.github.io/Par/), 261 bytes

```
` 0h0helibeb0c0n0o0f0nenamgalsip0s0clark0casctiv0crmnfeconicuzngageassebrkrrbsry0zrnbmotcrurhpdagcdinsnsbtei0xecsbalaceprndpmsmeugdtbdyhoertmybluhftaw0reosirptauhgtlpbbipoatrnfrraacthpau0nppuamcmbkcfesfmmdnolrrfdbsgbhhsmtdsrgcn`2%`uutfl0uuplv0uusuuo`3%+l✶´gΣ'0-
```

One byte is used per character, even `Σ`, since a specialized encoding is used. See [here](https://github.com/Ypnypn/Par/blob/gh-pages/README.md#the-encoding).

Input is Lisp-style, e.g. `(9 53 75 0 53 16 0 9 92 7)`

```
` 0h0hel...n`  ## Elements until Uut
2%             ## Split into pieces of size 2
`uutfl0u...o`  ## Elements from Uut
3%             ## Split into pieces of size 3
+              ## Combine into list of elements
l✶             ## Read array of numbers
´g             ## Find the element at each index
Σ              ## Concatenate
'0-            ## Remove all 0's
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.x, 295 bytes

Golfed code:

```
import re;print''.join([re.findall('[A-Z ][a-z]*',' HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo')[e]for e in i])
```

NB: to shave 8 bytes, output for this version is in mixed caps (doesn't break any rules), missing the `.lower()` ending

---

## <s>387 bytes</s>

Golfed code:

```
print''.join([' ,h,he,li,be,b,c,n,o,f,ne,na,mg,al,si,p,s,cl,ar,k,ca,sc,ti,v,cr,mn,fe,co,ni,cu,zn,ga,ge,as,se,br,kr,rb,sr,y,zr,nb,mo,tc,ru,rh,pd,ag,cd,in,sn,sb,te,i,xe,cs,ba,la,ce,pr,nd,pm,sm,eu,gd,tb,dy,ho,er,tm,yb,lu,hf,ta,w,re,os,ir,pt,au,hg,tl,pb,bi,po,at,rn,fr,ra,ac,th,pa,u,np,pu,am,cm,bk,cf,es,fm,md,no,lr,rf,db,sg,bh,hs,mt,ds,rg,cn,uut,fl,uup,lv,uus,uuo'.split(',')[e]for e in i])
```

---

> Input: **A list** or a string **of integers** from 1 to 118.

Usage: `i=[9,53,75,0,53,16,0,9,92,7]`

> Output: The words for each chemical element if possible. Otherwise return False, **throw an error**, or blank. Note in your program 0 must return a whitespace or newline. Ignore all integers not in range.

PS: used 2.x for the `print` statement without parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>347</s> 279 bytes

```js
l=>l.map(n=>" HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo".match(/[ A-Z][a-z]*/g)[n]||"").join``
```

### Explanation

Uses [@CSᵠ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7635/cs%E1%B5%A0)'s idea of seperating the element names by capital letters. Converting the output to all upper or lower case would add 14 bytes.

```js
l=>
  l.map(n=>                   // iterate through each number

    " HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo"
      .match(/[ A-Z][a-z]*/g) // split the elements by the first letter being upper-case

        [n]                   // add the element name to the output
          ||""                // add nothing if the number was out of range
  ).join``                    // return the output as a string
```

### Test

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="9 53 75 0 53 16 0 9 92 7" /><button onclick='result.innerHTML=(

l=>l.map(n=>" HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo".match(/[ A-Z][a-z]*/g)[n]||"").join``

)(input.value.split(" "))'>Go</button><pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## ES6, 396 bytes

A very trivial approach:

```
var C=c=>c.map(a=>(" .h.he.li.be.b.c.n.o.f.ne.na.mg.al.si.p.s.cl.ar.k.ca.sc.ti.v.cr.mn.fe.co.ni.cu.zn.ga.ge.as.se.br.kr.rb.sr.y.zr.nb.mo.tc.ru.rh.pd.ag.cd.in.sn.sb.te.i.xe.cs.ba.la.ce.pr.nd.pm.sm.eu.gd.tb.dy.ho.er.tm.yb.lu.hf.ta.w.re.os.ir.pt.au.hg.tl.pb.bi.po.at.rn.fr.ra.ac.th.pa.u.np.pu.am.cm.bk.cf.es.fm.md.no.lr.rf.db.sg.bh.hs.mt.ds.rg.cn.uut.fl.uup.lv.uus.uuo").split(".")[a]||"").join("");
```

[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/aLfkdpqq/)

Comment: no need for the `var` prefix and semicolon `;` at the end in codegolf. insta 5 bytes off

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 470 bytes

```
interface B{static void main(String[]a){for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)System.out.print(" ,h,he,li,be,b,c,n,o,f,ne,na,mg,al,si,p,s,cl,ar,k,ca,sc,ti,v,cr,mn,fe,co,ni,cu,zn,ga,ge,as,se,br,kr,rb,sr,y,zr,nb,mo,tc,ru,rh,pd,ag,cd,in,sn,sb,te,i,xe,cs,ba,la,ce,pr,nd,pm,sm,eu,gd,tb,dy,ho,er,tm,yb,lu,hf,ta,w,re,os,ir,pt,au,hg,tl,pb,bi,po,at,rn,fr,ra,ac,th,pa,u,np,pu,am,cm,bk,cf,es,fm,md,no,lr,rf,db,sg,bh,hs,mt,ds,rg,cn,uut,fl,uup,lv,uus,uuo".split(",")[Integer.parseInt(a[i])]);}}
```

Accepts input as command line arguments. Uses an interface declaration to shorten class/main declaration. It will *definitely* error for invalid input. Because Java.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 282

```
->a{a.each{|n|" HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo".bytes{|j|n-=1-j/96;n==-1&&$><<j.chr}}}
```

**Ungolfed in test program**

Each number in turn is assigned to `n`. We run through the magic string bytewise, decreasing `n` unless the ASCII code is more than 96. When `n` is -1 we print a byte from the magic string. As `n` remains the same until all characters for that element are printed, all characters for that element are printed. Out of range numbers are simply ignored.

```
f=->a{
  a.each{|n|
    " HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo".
    bytes{|j|n-=1-j/96;n==-1&&print(j.chr)}
  }
}


f[[59,8,24,95,49,0,15,92,40,99,0,95,60,0,27,4,0,27,53,9]]
```

**Output**

```
PrOCrAmIn PUZrEs AmNd CoBe CoIF
```

Mixed case. All lowercase would cost an extra 9. All uppercase would cost an extra 7.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>275</s> <s>273</s> 272 bytes

```
a=>a.map(b=>" HHeLiBeBCNOFNeNaMgAlSiPSClArKaCaScTiVCrMnFeCoNiCuZnGaGeAsSeBrKrRbSrYZrNbMoTcRuRhPdAgCdInSnSbTeIXeCsBaLaCePrNdPmSmEuGdTbDyHoErTmYbLuHfTaWReOsIrPtAuHgTlPbBiPoAtRnFrRaAcThPaUNpPuAmCmBkCfEsFmMdNoLrRfDbSgBhHsMtDsRgCnUutFlUupLvUusUuo".split(/(?=[A-Z])/)[b]).join``
```

You can try it here : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c93z34go/3/)

Comment: shave a byte by removing the `/g` flag, no need when splitting